# Creating arithmetic table using enums

Tags: java, math, enums

I was working some of the example and got stuck on this question:

You are to develop a program that prints out the multiplication or addition table given the users start and end range and type of table.
The program will make use of 2D arrays to calculate the table.
The program will make use of the System.out.printf() method to allow formatted output.
The program will have TWO methods with the following name and signature:
public void createTable(int begin, int finish, TableType tableType)
public void printTable()
An additional method to check on arguments passed in to main will be provided (called argumentCheck()). This method will return true if the arguments passed in are valid and will set the data members: start, end and tableType.
There is no constructor, nor any other method (including overloaded methods).
The class will contain a data member (handle) for the table (a 2D array of type float), start and end (ints) for the start and end values of the table, and tableType (TableType) an enumerated type consisting of {MULT, ADD}.

```
public class ArithmeticTable {

private TableType tableType;
static int start = 1;
static int end = 10;

public enum TableType { 
    MULT {
        int result(int x, int y) {return x * y;}}, 
    ADD {
        int result(int x, int y) {return x + y;}}
}

public boolean argumentCheck(String[] args){
if(args.length!=3){
  System.err.println("Usage: Main <type> <start> <stop>");
  System.err.println("\tWhere <type> is one of +, \"*\"");
  System.err.println("\tand <start> is between 1 and 100");
  System.err.println("\tand <stop> is between 1 and 100");
  System.err.println("\tand start < stop");
  return false;
}        

if(args[0].charAt(0) == '+')
  tableType = TableType.ADD;
else
  tableType = TableType.MULT;
  int sta;
  int sto;

  try{
    sta = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    sto = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.err.println("Usage: Main <type> <start> <stop>");
    System.err.println("\tWhere <type> is one of +, -, \"*\", /");
    System.err.println("\tand <start> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand <stop> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand start < stop");
    return false;
  }

  if((sta < 1 || sta > 100)||((sto < 1 || sto > 100))){
    System.err.println("Usage: Main <type> <start> <stop>");
    System.err.println("\tWhere <type> is one of +, -, \"*\", /");
    System.err.println("\tand <start> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand <stop> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand start < stop");
    return false;
  }

  if(sta >= sto){
    System.err.println("Usage: Main <type> <start> <stop>");
    System.err.println("\tWhere <type> is one of +, -, \"*\", /");
    System.err.println("\tand <start> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand <stop> is between 1 and 100");
    System.err.println("\tand start < stop");
    return false;
  }

start = sta;
end = sto;
return true;
 }

public void createTable(int begin, int finish, TableType tableType)
{
    int i, result;
    for(i = begin; i <= finish; i++){
        switch(tableType){
            case MULT:
                result = begin * finish;
                break;
            case ADD:
                result = begin + finish;
                break;
            default:
                result = begin * finish;
                break;
        }
    }


}

public void printTable()  
{

}

public static void main(String[] args){
ArithmeticTable table = new ArithmeticTable();
if (table.argumentCheck(args)){
  table.createTable(table.start, table.end, table.tableType);
  table.printTable();
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying make enums to have basic operand method and put symbols ("*", and "+") to make table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at Java 8 Functions?

Comment: hmm? which one should i look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
public enum TableType { 

    MULT, 
    ADD;

    public static TableType get(char operand) {
        return (operand == '+') ? ADD : ((operand == '*') ? MULT : null);
    }

    public int result(int x, int y) {
        return (this == ADD) ? (x + y) : (x * y);
    }
}

...

TableType example = TableType.get('*');
System.out.println(example.result(4, 4)); // 16
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to do with Java 8 Functions. For example:

```
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add =      (Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b; // or Integer::sum
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> multiply = (Integer a, Integer b) -> a * b;
    System.out.println("1 + 2 = " + add.apply(1, 2));
    System.out.println("2 * 3 = " + multiply.apply(2, 3));
```